# Como utilizar um sinal aritmético para separar um valor do outro em um String matemática?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora que, no final do código, executa uma função chamada `mostrarResultado()`, essa função recebe a String do `campoTexto` da tela, Ex:("2+3"), e eu quero que qualquer que seja o operador(que está guardado dentro de uma variável operacao), seja o caractere que separa uma String da outra. 
Porém, ao executar o código, ocorre uma `Fatal Exception`, na linha 3 do código que segue abaixo, da função implementada até o momento. Desde já agradeço.

```
    public void mostrarResultado(){
    String texto =  campoTexto.getText().toString();

    String[] valores = texto.split(operacao);

    float numA = Float.parseFloat(valores[0]);
    float numB = Float.parseFloat(valores[1]);
    float result = 0;

    switch(operacao) {
        case "+":
            result = numA + numB;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = numA - numB;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = numA * numB;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = numA / numB;
            break;
    }

    campoTexto.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Comment: De onde vem esta variável `operação`?

Comment: Ela é uma variável global que é utilizada em outra função também. Essa outra função é a que guarda o valor do operador dentro da variável operacao.

Comment: E o que tem nela. Você precisa colocar toda informação necessária pra gente entender o código. Você deve [edit] a pergunta para colocar tudo que é relevante.

Comment: @BrunoToledo, favor indicar se minha resposta ajuda em alguma coisa, pois realmente da maneira que sua pergunta está fica complicado ajudar. Caso minha resposta não atenda, favor sinalizar para eu poder deletá-la. Sobre o seu código, vi que você trocou o conteúdo do Split. Antes tinha uma string chamada "operacao", agora tem uma variável chamada operacao. Se você não colocar mais código e indicar como você obtém essa operacao, fica muito complicado te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o `split` pelo operador (+,-,*,/) e não pela String `operacao` como mostrado no seu código.

Para isso, uma abordagem simples (já que você está aprendendo), seria verificar se a String contém o operador, se contiver você faz o split por ele.

Exemplo:

```
String texto =  campoTexto.getText().toString(); 
String[] valores;

if (texto.contains("+"))
  valores = texto.split("+");
else if (texto.contains("-"))
  valores = texto.split("-");
```